# Unity how can I put multiple if statements in OnTriggerEnter2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, game-development

Good day, I'm trying to create an enemy that damages the player because that's what enemies do. I have figured it out on how to do this the only problem is that the enemy kills the player almost instantly and is too overpowered... I was trying to put some cooldown before the enemy strikes again but unfortunately, an `OnTriggerEnter2D` seems to only accept 1 if statement.

```
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
        //What iam trying to achieve but this doesn't work
        if(Time.time > nextDamageTime) { 
            if(col.CompareTag("Player")){
                player.curHealth -= 1;
                Debug.Log("Enemy damaged player!");
                nextDamageTime = Time.time + cooldownTime;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't support only one if statement that's for sure, it looks like you have some other bug. I assume this script is attached to the enemy and you have a reference to player, what's the actual observed behaviour? Does anything happen at all?

Comment: @Charleh That's correct! Using the above code doesn't do anything at all but when I remove the `if(Time.time > nextDamageTime)` It kills the player instantly...

Comment: @SamuëlTieman Can you trace out/debug the values of Time.time and nextDamageTime when this script is running? Also, what do you mean it only accepts 1 if statement? What's the error if you put a condition such as `if(true){}` ?

Comment: Are sure you don't maybe want to rather use `OnTriggerStay` for getting the method called repeatedly like `Update` instead of only once?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is c#. There is nothing that can anyhow control how many `if` blocks you open within a method.

So, no there is no limit on conditions and `if` blocks within `OnTriggerEnter2D`!

---

I don't see a direct problem in your code actually except maybe: [`OnTrigggerEntet2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) is called exactly **once** namely in the moment the trigger enters without exiting. So if this already instantly kills the player then reducing `1` might simply be a too high value.

With the timer nothing happens because as said it is called only once, so in the case the timer wasn't finished yet nothing happens until the enemy leaves and re-enters eventually.

---

You might want to rather use [`OnTriggerStay2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html) which is rather called **every frame** as long as a trigger collides.

```
float timer;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider other)
{
    // reset the timer so the first hit happens immediately
    timer = 0;
}

private void OnTriggerStays2D(Collider other)
{
    if(!col.CompareTag("Player")) return;

    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

    if(timer > 0) return;

    timer = cooldownTime;
    player.curHealth -= 1;
}
```

Which now would reduce the players health by `1` every `cooldownTime` seconds.

---

In general especially for multiple enemies I personally would rather give the player the control over timer after it was last hit so the player itself has kind of an invincible time. Enemies can simply attack like they would do usually but the player itself decides whether the damage counts or not.